# Writing an R function, using "for-loop", to compute the arithmetic mean from vectors with numeric data?

Tags: r, for-loop, mean

I need to write a function that does the above, basically. I would like it to be able to apply it to any numeric vector. I am very new to R so I'm struggling to get this off the ground. I appreciate any help!

Comment: `sm <- 0; count<-0;  for(i in  vector) {sm <- sm + i; count <- count + 1}; sm/count`

Comment: Thank you! Would there be a way to turn this into a function?

Comment: Homework problems are welcome, but we ask that you show some of what you tried and where you got stuck. Do you have a sample vector you're trying to test code on? Are you familiar with function syntax?

Comment: Ah, @GregorThomas, I see.

Comment: I would recommend giving yourself a small test vector, say `x <- c(4, 7, 3)`. Start working on your loop, see what you can do. Then when you've got a working loop, see if you can get it to work on another test vector that's a little longer. Then when that's done, try to put it in a function.

Comment: Ok, makes sense - sorry for not including much. I was just trying to use a basic vector by typing something like x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6). I know very little about function syntax but am trying to teach myself.

Comment: That's great. If you show us what you've got, tell us your thoughts, and describe where you're stuck, we can help you over a specific hurdle, and you will learn a lot. If someone just shows you a solution here, you will not learn very much.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than write your own function use `mean()`, which comes with base R:

```
numbers <- c(11, 3, 4.2, 0, -12)
numbers
result <- mean(numbers)
```